# Automate Deletion of File from terminal

Tags: python, delete, rm

I want to write a Python script that will automate my commands without waiting for user input.

My python script will delete the least played video. When I execute the command:

```
rm video_123.mp4
```

it asks for user input:

```
rm: remove write-protected regular file 'video_123.mp4'?
```

to which on giving input **y** it deletes the file.

How will I write that in python script to automatically delete the file?

Comment: Does `rm -f video_123.mp4` remove the file without warning ?

Comment: The admin who set up your system probably aliased `rm` as alias for `rm -i`. By default `rm` doesn't prompt for confirmation, only when `-i` flag is used. Check your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`

Comment: Yes. It does. Thank you. But anyways ... what could have been the python script ?

Comment: `-f` is of course easier in this case, but you could also use `yes | rm video_123.mp4` too.

Comment: In what circumstances would a python system call expand a user's aliases? `subprocess.call()` doesn't seem to, at least.

Comment: @steeldriver There seems to be an alias, but OP didn't mention running `rm` in Python, and yes, Python wouldn't expand user aliases.  This is more of an XY problem - OP is trying to fix one problem, while the actual one is entirely different.

Comment: @ron123456 In pure Python you'd do `os.remove("video_123.mp4")`